# Drawing board game pieces in an array

Tags: android, arrays

I cannot get the array to display rooks or bishops (r & b). I need them displayed on the row in front of the King (k), G, s, n, l.
The case statements should run through and draw all the pieces on the board, however it will only run through 18 times, then crash, but I'm sure I declared the array to have 40 pieces (In shogi each player starts with 20 pieces).
The case statements also ignore case r and b at the moment.

```
    private void setUpNewPieces(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        //Sets back row.
        pieces[20 * i] = new Piece ('K', i, 4, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 1] = new Piece('G', i, 3, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 2] = new Piece('s', i, 2, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 3] = new Piece('n', i, 1, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 4] = new Piece('l', i, 0, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 5] = new Piece('G', i, 5, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 6] = new Piece('s', i, 6, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 7] = new Piece('n', i, 7, (8 * i));
        pieces[(20 * i) + 8] = new Piece('l', i, 8, (8 * i));

        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 2; i3++){
            pieces[(20 * i) + 9] = new Piece('b', i, i3, (7 * i));
            pieces[(20 * i) + 10] = new Piece('r', i, i3, (7 * 1));
        }
        //Set pawns.
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 9; i2++){
            pieces[(18 * i) + 9 + i2] = new Piece('p', i, i2,(6 * i));
        }
        Log.d("setUpNewPieces", "pawnDone");
    }
    Log.d("setUpNewPieces", "nonPawnDone");
}//END private void newPieces()



private void updateBoard(){
    Location field;
    int x, y;

    String theArray;
    for(int jkl=0;jkl < pieces.length;jkl++){
        theArray = jkl + ": " + String.valueOf(pieces[jkl].type) + "-" + String.valueOf(pieces[jkl].direction);
        Log.d("TheArray",theArray);
    }

    //Draw pieces.
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        field = pieces [i].getLocation();
        Log.d("DrawPieces - i",String.valueOf(i));
        Log.d("DrawPieces - type",String.valueOf(pieces[i].type));
        Log.d("DrawPieces - direction",String.valueOf(pieces[i].direction));
        x = field.getX();
        y = field.getY();

        if(!field.isEmpty()){
            switch (pieces[i].direction){
            case 0:
                Log.d("pieces[i].d...","case0Start");
                switch (pieces[i].type){
                case 'K':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.king);
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.gold);
                    break;
                case 's':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.silver);
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.silver_p);
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.knight);
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.knight_p);
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.lance);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.lance_p);
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.bishop);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.bishop_p);
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.rook);
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.rook_p);
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.pawn);
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.pawn_p);
                    break;
                }//END switch (pieces[i].type) WITHIN case 0
                Log.d("pieces[i].d...","case0Finish");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d("pieces[i].d...","case1Start");
                switch (pieces[i].type){
                case 'K':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.king_rot);
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.gold_rot);
                    break;
                case 's':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.silver_rot);
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.silver_p_rot);
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.knight_rot);
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.knight_p_rot);
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.lance_rot);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.lance_p_rot);
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.bishop_rot);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.bishop_p_rot);
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.rook_rot);
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.rook_p_rot);
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.pawn_rot);
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    gameBoardView[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.pawn_p_rot);
                    break;
                }//END switch (pieces[i].type) WITHIN case 1
                Log.d("pieces[i].d...","case1Finish");
                break;

            }//END switch (pieces[i].direction)
            Log.d("updateBoardDrawPieces", "drawDone");
        }//END if(!field.isEmpty())
    }//END for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)

}//END updateBoard{
```

Here is the full error log:

```
03-01 14:59:55.262: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(579): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-01 14:59:55.272: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(579): CheckJNI is ON
03-01 14:59:55.522: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(579): --- registering native functions ---
03-01 14:59:56.742: DEBUG/dalvikvm(184): GC_EXPLICIT freed 121 objects / 6392 bytes in 153ms
03-01 14:59:56.852: DEBUG/PackageParser(68): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl73743.tmp
03-01 14:59:57.242: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 14819 objects / 820272 bytes in 171ms
03-01 14:59:58.022: INFO/PackageManager(68): Removing non-system package:com.coursework.shogi
03-01 14:59:58.022: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Force stopping package com.coursework.shogi uid=10036
03-01 14:59:58.252: DEBUG/PackageManager(68): Scanning package com.coursework.shogi
03-01 14:59:58.252: INFO/PackageManager(68): Package com.coursework.shogi codePath changed from /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-2.apk to /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
03-01 14:59:58.272: INFO/PackageManager(68): /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-1.apk changed; unpacking
03-01 14:59:58.322: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.coursework.shogi-1.apk' ---
03-01 14:59:58.692: DEBUG/dalvikvm(586): DexOpt: load 64ms, verify 143ms, opt 4ms
03-01 14:59:58.705: DEBUG/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.coursework.shogi-1.apk' (success) ---
03-01 14:59:58.712: WARN/PackageManager(68): Code path for pkg : com.coursework.shogi changing from /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-2.apk to /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-1.apk
03-01 14:59:58.712: WARN/PackageManager(68): Resource path for pkg : com.coursework.shogi changing from /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-2.apk to /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-1.apk
03-01 14:59:58.712: DEBUG/PackageManager(68):   Activities: com.coursework.shogi.Shogi com.coursework.shogi.Instructions com.coursework.shogi.Game com.coursework.shogi.Prefs
03-01 14:59:58.732: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Force stopping package com.coursework.shogi uid=10036
03-01 14:59:58.932: INFO/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.coursework.shogi-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.coursework.shogi-1.apk@classes.dex
03-01 14:59:58.932: DEBUG/PackageManager(68): New package installed in /data/app/com.coursework.shogi-1.apk
03-01 14:59:59.192: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Force stopping package com.coursework.shogi uid=10036
03-01 14:59:59.332: DEBUG/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 796 objects / 43384 bytes in 117ms
03-01 14:59:59.742: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(68): no available voice recognition services found
03-01 15:00:00.182: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12265 objects / 682336 bytes in 190ms
03-01 15:00:00.262: DEBUG/dalvikvm(165): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1580 objects / 80600 bytes in 895ms
03-01 15:00:00.342: INFO/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.coursework.shogi-2.apk@classes.dex
03-01 15:00:00.372: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(579): Shutting down VM
03-01 15:00:00.382: DEBUG/dalvikvm(579): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-01 15:00:00.412: INFO/AndroidRuntime(579): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-01 15:00:01.212: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(592): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-01 15:00:01.212: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(592): CheckJNI is ON
03-01 15:00:01.582: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(592): --- registering native functions ---
03-01 15:00:02.673: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.coursework.shogi/.Shogi }
03-01 15:00:02.942: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(592): Shutting down VM
03-01 15:00:02.973: DEBUG/dalvikvm(592): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-01 15:00:03.052: INFO/AndroidRuntime(592): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-01 15:00:03.104: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Start proc com.coursework.shogi for activity com.coursework.shogi/.Shogi: pid=599 uid=10036 gids={}
03-01 15:00:04.702: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed activity com.coursework.shogi/.Shogi: 1768 ms (total 2033641 ms)
03-01 15:00:07.112: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.coursework.shogi/.Game }
03-01 15:00:07.622: DEBUG/setContentView(599): Called in protected void
03-01 15:00:07.652: DEBUG/setUpObjects(599): setUpGameBoardViewCalled
03-01 15:00:07.682: DEBUG/setUpObjects(599): initialseGridViews

It calls the class 40 times, as I wanted...

03-01 15:00:07.692: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.692: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.692: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.702: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.722: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.722: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.722: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.722: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.734: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.734: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.741: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.741: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.752: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.752: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.752: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.752: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.762: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.762: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.772: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/publicClassPiece(599): Started
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/setUpObjects(599): lastMoveInitialised
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/setUpObjects(599): Called in protected void
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/setUpNewPieces(599): pawnDone
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/setUpNewPieces(599): pawnDone
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/setUpNewPieces(599): nonPawnDone
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/setUpNewPieces(599): Called in protected void

Here TheArray is only called 18 times, I was told this is because I only have 18 spaces in the array, and it then crashes because there is no more room. It calls the back row of pieces and the pawns, ignoring the rook and bishop; and never getting to the second player
(Sorry if I repeated myself, but i thought this may help).

03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 0: K-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 1: G-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 2: s-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 3: n-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 4: l-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 5: G-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 6: s-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 7: n-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 8: l-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 9: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 10: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 11: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 12: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 13: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.792: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 14: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.802: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 15: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.802: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 16: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.802: DEBUG/TheArray(599): 17: p-0
03-01 15:00:07.802: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(599): Shutting down VM
03-01 15:00:07.802: WARN/dalvikvm(599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coursework.shogi/com.coursework.shogi.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.coursework.shogi.Game$Piece.access$0(Game.java:72)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.coursework.shogi.Game.updateBoard(Game.java:434)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at com.coursework.shogi.Game.onCreate(Game.java:30)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-01 15:00:07.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(599):     ... 11 more
03-01 15:00:07.904: WARN/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity com.coursework.shogi/.Game
03-01 15:00:07.912: WARN/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity com.coursework.shogi/.Shogi
03-01 15:00:08.413: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45009650 com.coursework.shogi/.Game}
03-01 15:00:14.871: DEBUG/dalvikvm(184): GC_EXPLICIT freed 163 objects / 11848 bytes in 158ms
03-01 15:00:19.523: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44ff8a00 com.coursework.shogi/.Shogi}
03-01 15:00:19.523: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{45009650 com.coursework.shogi/.Game}
03-01 15:00:19.912: DEBUG/dalvikvm(262): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47 objects / 2264 bytes in 154ms
```

Here is the class for the pieces:

```
public class Piece {
    /**Type List:
     * K = King
     * G = Gold General
     * s = Silver General
     * S = Promoted Silver
     * n = Knight
     * N = Promoted Knight
     * l = Lance
     * L = Promoted Lance
     * b = Bishop
     * B = Dragon Horse (Promoted Bishop)
     * r = Rook
     * R = Dragon (Promoted Rook)
     * p = Pawn
     * P = Token (Promoted Pawn)
     */
    private char type;//see above for the variables used for the types of piece..
    private int direction;//0 = black/gote, 1 = white/sente. 
    private Location field = new Location();
    private boolean moved;
    private boolean onBoard;//if false, the piece will be in a token reservoir.
        //private bool onBoard not implemented

    public Piece(char setType, int setDirection, int setX, int setY){
        this.type = setType;
        this.direction = setDirection;
        this.field.setX(setX);
        this.field.setY(setY);
        this.moved = false;
        this.onBoard = true;
    }

    public Piece(){
        this.type = 'K';
        this.direction = 0;
        this.field.empty();
        this.moved = false;
        this.onBoard = true;
    }

    public void copyFrom(Piece p){
        type = p.getType();
        direction = p.getDirection();
        field.setX(p.getLocation().getX());
        field.setY(p.getLocation().getY());
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        return field;
    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y, boolean move){
        field.setX(x);
        field.setY(y);
        if (move){
            moved = true;
        }
    }

    public int getX(){
        return field.getX();
    }

    public int getY(){
        return field.getY();
    }

    public void setX(int x){
        field.setX(x);
    }

    public void setY(int y){
        field.setY(y);
    }

    public boolean compareLocation(Location l){
        return field.equals(l);
    }

    public boolean compareLocation(int x, int y){
        return ((x == field.getX()) && (y == field.getY()));
    }

    public int getDirection(){
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(int i){
        direction = i;
    }

    public char getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int i){
        type = (char) i;
    }

    public boolean hasMoved(){
        return moved;
    }

    public void setMoved(byte b){
        moved = (b == 1);
    }

}//END public class Piece
```

Comment: Error log will be much appreciated

Comment: Is there a way to format the error log when I post it? At the moment it just comes out in one big line, and it's difficult to read.

@slayton
I've re-wrote the code, and tried changing some values, but nothing seems to work for what I've tried

Comment: copy and paste the entire stack trace in a single code block

Comment: My emulator is on another computer, so I need to copy it into a document then paste it on the computer with access to the Internet; it will display it correctly, but it's long and hard to read. I shall point out the bits I think are important, although I could be wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should this:

```
pieces[(20 * i) + 10] = new Piece('r', i, i3, (7 * 1));
```

be this:

```
pieces[(20 * i) + 10] = new Piece('r', i, i3, (7 * i));
```

---

Also, pieces 0 through 10 are instered in `pieces`, but then you overwrite 9 and 10 (your b and r pieces) with the pawns.

---

Suggestion, why dont you create an int pieceNum and then use:

```
pieces[pieceNum++] = ...
```

instead of calculating the offset.

---

I'm not even looking at your constructor args because you didn't post that class.  There are enough problems on the calculation of the offset into the `pieces` array.

On the first pass of this code (while your outer i variable is = 1), look at the OFFSET (in the comments):

```
pieces[20 * i] = new Piece ('K', i, 4, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 0
pieces[(20 * i) + 1] = new Piece('G', i, 3, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 1
pieces[(20 * i) + 2] = new Piece('s', i, 2, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 2
pieces[(20 * i) + 3] = new Piece('n', i, 1, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 3
pieces[(20 * i) + 4] = new Piece('l', i, 0, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 4
pieces[(20 * i) + 5] = new Piece('G', i, 5, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 5
pieces[(20 * i) + 6] = new Piece('s', i, 6, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 6
pieces[(20 * i) + 7] = new Piece('n', i, 7, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 7
pieces[(20 * i) + 8] = new Piece('l', i, 8, (8 * i)); // OFFSET = 8

for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 2; i3++){             
   pieces[(20 * i) + 9] = new Piece('b', i, i3, (7 * i)); // OFFSET = 9 for both bishops, the 2nd overwrites the 1st
   pieces[(20 * i) + 10] = new Piece('r', i, i3, (7 * 1)); // OFFSET = 10 for both rooks, the 2nd overwrites the 1st
}         

for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 9; i2++){             
   pieces[(18 * i) + 9 + i2] = new Piece('p', i, i2,(6 * i)); // OFFSET = 9 thru 16, overwriting the bishop and rook set above
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that myself. Although I have no idea how it became a 1...

Comment: I thought the (7 * i) for b and r would be displayed in the row above the pawns, or do I need to move the closing bracket of the for loop with i3?

Comment: Thank you for the offset comments. I will change the loop for the bishops and rooks to read 'for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 1; i3++){' so i don't have them overwriting each other. 

However, I don't understand how to get the rook and bishop to display in a row inbetween the back row and the row with the pawns. Is this not set by (n * i).
The first loop will be displayed in row 8, the second loop in row 7 and the pawns in row 6?

Comment: I can post the class for Pieces that I made if it would help.

Comment: Yes please post it.  Please note that in your setUpNewPieces the pawns are also overwriting your Bishop and Rook too, that +9 should be +13.  And also you are adding 9 pawns (i2 goes from 0 to 8), which I assume is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I am grateful for it.

I do need 9 pawns, and there should be 3 rows of pieces, with the pawns all on one row, the bishop and rook on a row with just them, and then the back row, which needs 9 pieces too.

Comment: @OneGlove You said their were 40 pieces, but I see the following: K,Gx2,sx2,nx2,lx2,bx2,rx2,px9 which is 22 x 2 playes for 44 total pieces...did I miss something?

Comment: That was my fault for messing up the code, there should only be one bishop and rook for each player. I have changed that bit in the program. It now loops through only once for drawing the bishop and rook.

Comment: It was changing the id of the piece, I thought having them in a different row would allow it to work. Apart from that I just had to change some y values so the rook and bishop would display correctly for each side. Thank you tcavin!